# Why is nested nth-of-type selector not working?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What I need is, the textbox inside the first occurrence of class ".has-error" to be highlighted in red. I tried to nest the :nth-of-type selector as below. It works only when the div with id "name" has the "has-error" class. But I doesn't work in other scenarios. Can someone please explain me the reason why it is not working?

```css
.fields input[type="text"] {
 color: #000;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
.fields > .error:nth-of-type(1) > .has-error:nth-of-type(1) input[type="text"] {
 color: #f00;
 border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="fields">
 <div class="col error">
  <div id="name" class="input">
   <input type="text" name="name" />
  </div>
  <div id="email" class="input has-error">
   <input type="text" name="email" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col error">
  <div id="age" class="input has-error">
   <input type="text" name="age" />
  </div>
  <div id="phone" class="input has-error">
   <input type="text" name="phone" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) matches only elements and not class names.

Comment: My Bad. Looks like i dint read the CSS3 spec correctly. Thank you for spotting it.